# Docusign: Sample Code Cannot Connect to '/app-shell'?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the sample code provided by DocuSign in the Github project "qs-01-node-embed-signing-ceremony-master".

I've obtained and added my accessToken and accountId.

When the sample code is run via `npm start`, it displays an error message in the browser window:

> Cannot GET /app-shell

Chrome dev tools shows this:

[image]

The sample code appears to contain no file named `app-shell`.

How can I correct this?

Comment: What version of node.js are you using?

Comment: Node version 8.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are unaddressed caching anomalies with the demo code. Selecting "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" in Chrome fixed it.

After successfully signing the test doc, I still got the "Cannot GET /app-shell" message, but that glitch seems to be specific to the demo code.

Hopefully this is enough of a test for me to start implementing Docusign in my app.

Note: It appears that this demo was not built with create-react-app or other tech that auto-rebuilds and reloads the page when the source is edited.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this sample code and tried it from scratch. I cannot find a file named workbox-core.dev.js in there and when I tried it - it worked just fine.
Please check if this is not something in your environment that may be causing this.
Try a new fresh clone from scratch just in case.

Comment: I must be leaving out a step. I just >>>re-downloaded the source from https://github.com/docusign/qs-01-node-embed-signing-ceremony. >>>got my accessToken and accountId from Docusign Developer Sandbox and added them to index.js >>>put a valid email address into USER_EMAIL >>>ran npm install and npm start.  I got the same errors as before. What am I leaving out?

Comment: I did exactly these steps. I assume you use master branch?

Comment: my guess is your nodeJS environment has some other stuff.

Comment: I do use master branch.  This code defines its own node.js environment in terms of what npm libraries it imports, its build system, etc. Do you have anything specific in mind when you mention that the nodeJS environment could have other stuff?

Comment: I don't. can you use a different clean VM to try it there?